# Regex pattern match before and after hyphen

Tags: c#, regex

I've a string like this:

```
"(33) 3669-0210 Gerencia"
```

I trying to get all the numbers after/before - (hyphen) till find a white space on both the end using Regex in C#.

Output should be

```
"3669-0210"
```

Can someone help with Regex expression which will work in C#?

Answer (score 6):

You can use this expression:

```
\b\d+-\d+\b
```

It's a non-capturing *word boundary* designator, followed by one or more digits, followed by a hyphen, one or more digits, and finally another non-capturing word boundary.

If the numbers to match are always 4 digits long, this is more exact:

```
\b\d{4}-\d{4}\b
```

Comment: `\d` doesn't capture `x` or `Gerencia` either.

Comment: @Stefan Oh, of course you're right! It was a dumb comment, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3):

`"[0-9]+-[0-9]+"` this should be enough

Explanation:

`[0-9]+`    - at least one number

`-`         - hyphen

`[0-9]+`    - at least one number

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression:

```
\S+-\S+
```

It's one or more non-whitespace characters, followed by a hyphen, followed by one or more non-whitespace characters.

Comment: That would match a lot of things other than "numbers-numbers".